# How can I watch for changes to google calendar events on a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

I've successfully listed google calendar events on a flutter app by using [EventsResource/list](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/calendar.v3/EventsResource/list.html). But how can I watch for changes to events? There is [EventsResource.watch](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/calendar.v3/EventsResource/watch.html) method. But I couldn't find a way how I can use it.

For example:

```dart
CalendarApi calendarApi = ...;
calendarApi.calendarList.watch(request)  // how to use this?;
```

The `watch()` method takes a `Channel request`. A [`Channel`](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/$shared/$Channel-class.html) seems to be just a container for HTTP metadata for specifying a webhook. Similarly, the `watch()` mehtod returns a [`Channel`](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/$shared/$Channel-class.html) object.
This looks like one has to somehow set up a webhook for my app that receives notifications from the Calendar API and forwards them to the client.

The ideal situation would be to have a subscription in the client, perhaps a `Stream<Event>` which one can listen to and get changes directly in the client.

Is there a way to do this with the Calendar API?

Comment: Please edit our question include [example] and describe any issues you are having.  Show us what you have tried and whats not working with it.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your feedback. I don't know what to pass for the client parameter of the [watch method](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/calendar.v3/EventsResource/watch.html). I could not find any example code of the method.

Comment: I think you should read the docs about it so that you understand how to set it up [Push](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push)  as far as i can see there is no client parameter.  You should post [example] its hard to help without seeing what you are doing.   Please post an example or i will have to vote close your question as lacking an example and not having enough information to solve it.  please read [ask]